# Printing to a specific printer in Crystal Reports

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I am using "Crystal Reports XI release 2" I am trying to find the setting that will let me pick a specific printer for my report to print to. I want report A to print to my default printer, but I want printer B to print to a separate printer. From what I have looked at online it seems as though this option is not avaliable in my version of CR that I am using. Any input?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your question is that report A is already behaving as you want it to, but you'd like to specify a default printer for report B. If this is correct, open report B and navigate to File --> Print. Here you can select the printer, page size, and tray, which will all be saved with the report and used as the default.

[image: print setup]

You may also need to uncheck "No Printer" and choose the desired printer under Page Setup.

[image]